# If else condition Apache 301 redirect

Tags: apache-2.4, http, httpd, 301-redirect

I have multiple URL's that looks something like this :

- stage-app-platform-com.something.com
- stage.something.com
- stage1.something1.com

I wanted to create an Apache 301 redirect rule which, if the URL contains the pattern **app-platform** should forward to stage1.app.com and any other request hitting the server should be redirected to stage2.app.com. To do so, I wrote the following redirect rule:

```
RewriteRule ^stage-app-platform-com$ https://stage1.app.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://stage2.app.com/ [L,R=301]
```

Now the second rule which states all the traffic hitting should be re-directed to *https://stage2.app.com/* works but the first one doesn't seem to work. If the first URL is requested Apache forwards to the *https://stage2.app.com/* instead of *https://stage1.app.com/*

As I am pretty much new to writing re-write rules, I am finding it a bit difficult. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. But first explicity clear your browser cache. Redirects are often cached.

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /^stage-app-platform-com\./">
   Redirect permanent https://stage1.app.com/
</if>
<else>
   Redirect permanent https://stage2.app.com/
</else>
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule`'s don't see the hostname part of the URL. What you need to use is `RewriteCond` as well, something like:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^stage-app-platform-com\."
RewriteRule .* https://stage1.app.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule .* https://stage2.app.com/ [L,R=301]
```

This causes the first `RewriteRule` to apply only if the `RewriteCond` condition matches. If not it should then fall through to the second `RewriteRule`.

The `mod_rewrite` documentation is here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Thanks a ton for the reply, but can you please shed some light what these 3 lines of code are doing?

Comment: Somehow it doesn't seem to work. It is still forwarding everything to https://stage2.app.com/

Comment: So follow http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging and capture the rewrite logs for a request to see what's going on and update your question.